# Export problem with Pipelining data in Datatables

Tags: javascript, node.js, datatables, ejs

```
    <!-- end row -->
<div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 no-padding">


    <!-- Widget ID (each widget will need unique ID)-->
    <div class="jarviswidget" role="widget">

        <!-- widget div-->
        <div role="content">

            <!-- widget content -->
            <div class="widget-body no-padding">

                <form class="smart-form" method="post" id="filterForm">

                    <header>
                        Search
                    </header>

                    <fieldset>

                       <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-6">
                           <label class="label">Filter</label>
                           <label class="input" style="width: 90%">
                               <input type="text"  id="filter" name="filter"  placeholder="Branch Code">
                           </label>
                       </div>

                        <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-6" class="float-left">
                            <section class="col-md-5 col-lg-6">
                                <label class="label">From Date</label>
                                <label class="input">
                                    <input type="text" name="fromDate" id="fromDate" value="" placeholder="Start Date" class="input-ms feildWidth95per"  />
                                </label>
                            </section>
                            <section class="col-md-5 col-lg-6">
                                <label class="label">To Date</label>
                                <label class="input">
                                    <input type="text" name="toDate" id="toDate" value="" placeholder="End Date" class="input-ms feildWidth95per"  />
                                </label>
                            </section>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-6">
                            <label class="label">Branch Status: </label>
                            <div class="inline-group">
                                <label class="radio">
                                    <input type="radio" checked="checked" name="status" value="1">
                                    <i></i>Active</label>
                                <label class="radio">
                                    <input type="radio" name="status" value="0">
                                    <i></i>Inactive</label>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                       <!-- <input type="hidden" name="status" value="1" /> -->

                    </fieldset>

                    <footer>
                        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" id="btnExport">
                            Export
                        </button>

                        <button class="btn btn-primary submit" type="submit" disabled="disabled">
                            Search
                        </button>

                    </footer>
                </form>

            </div>
            <!-- end widget content -->

        </div>
        <!-- end widget div -->

    </div>
    <!-- end widget -->
</div>
<section id="widget-grid" class="">

    <!-- row -->
    <div class="row">

        <!-- NEW WIDGET START -->
        <article class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">

            <!-- Widget ID (each widget will need unique ID)-->
            <div class="jarviswidget jarviswidget-color-darken" id="wid-id-0" data-widget-editbutton="false" data-widget-deletebutton="false" data-widget-togglebutton="false" data-widget-colorbutton="false">
                <header>
                    <span class="widget-icon"> <i class="fa fa-table"></i> </span>
                    <h2>List Of New Branches </h2>
                </header>

                <!-- widget div-->
                <div>
                    <!-- end widget edit box -->

                    <!-- widget content -->
                    <div class="widget-body no-padding">

                        <table id="branches" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" width="100%">
                            <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th data-hide="phone">Sr. No.</th>
                                <th data-hide="phone">Branch Code</th>
                                <th data-hide="phone,tablet">Parent Code</th>
                                <th data-hide="phone,tablet">Date Created</th>
                                <th data-hide="phone,tablet"><i class="fa txt-color-blue hidden-md hidden-sm hidden-xs"></i> Branch Limit</th>
                                <th data-hide="phone,tablet"><i class="fa txt-color-blue hidden-md hidden-sm hidden-xs"></i> Status </th>

                            </tr>
                            </thead>

                        </table>

                    </div>
                    <!-- end widget content -->

                </div>
                <!-- end widget div -->

            </div>
            <!-- end widget -->
        </article>
        <!-- WIDGET END -->

    </div>

    <!-- end row -->

    <!-- end row -->

</section>

<style>
    .feildWidth95per{
        width: 95% !important;
    }
    .radio{
        margin-right: 5px !important    ;
    }
    #fromDate,fromDate{
        width: 90% !important;
    }
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
    pageSetUp();

    var  tabeleRef = "";

    // pagefunction
    var pagefunction = function() {

        /* // DOM Position key index //

         l - Length changing (dropdown)
         f - Filtering input (search)
         t - The Table! (datatable)
         i - Information (records)
         p - Pagination (paging)
         r - pRocessing
         < and > - div elements
         <"#id" and > - div with an id
         <"class" and > - div with a class
         <"#id.class" and > - div with an id and class

         Also see: http://legacy.datatables.net/usage/features
         */

        $.fn.dataTable.pipeline = function ( opts ) {
            // Configuration options
            var conf = $.extend( {
                pages: 5,     // number of pages to cache
                url: '',      // script url
                data: null,   // function or object with parameters to send to the server
                              // matching how `ajax.data` works in DataTables
                method: 'GET' // Ajax HTTP method
            }, opts );

            // Private variables for storing the cache
            var cacheLower = -1;
            var cacheUpper = null;
            var cacheLastRequest = null;
            var cacheLastJson = null;

            return function ( request, drawCallback, settings ) {
                var ajax          = filterButtonClicked;
                var requestStart  = request.start;
                var drawStart     = request.start;
                var requestLength = request.length;
                var requestEnd    = requestStart + requestLength;

                if ( settings.clearCache ) {
                    // API requested that the cache be cleared
                    ajax = true;
                    settings.clearCache = false;
                }
                else if ( cacheLower < 0 || requestStart < cacheLower || requestEnd > cacheUpper ) {
                    // outside cached data - need to make a request
                    ajax = true;
                }
                else if ( JSON.stringify( request.order )   !== JSON.stringify( cacheLastRequest.order ) ||
                    JSON.stringify( request.columns ) !== JSON.stringify( cacheLastRequest.columns ) ||
                    JSON.stringify( request.search )  !== JSON.stringify( cacheLastRequest.search )
                ) {
                    // properties changed (ordering, columns, searching)
                    ajax = true;
                }

                // Store the request for checking next time around
                cacheLastRequest = $.extend( true, {}, request );

                if ( ajax ) {
                    filterButtonClicked = false;
                    // Need data from the server
                    if ( requestStart < cacheLower ) {
                        requestStart = requestStart - (requestLength*(conf.pages-1));

                        if ( requestStart < 0 ) {
                            requestStart = 0;
                        }
                    }

                    cacheLower = requestStart;
                    cacheUpper = requestStart + (requestLength * conf.pages);


                    request.start = requestStart;
                    request.length = requestLength*conf.pages;

                    // Provide the same `data` options as DataTables.
                    if ( $.isFunction ( conf.data ) ) {
                        // As a function it is executed with the data object as an arg
                        // for manipulation. If an object is returned, it is used as the
                        // data object to submit
                        var d = conf.data( request );
                        if ( d ) {
                            $.extend( request, d );
                        }
                    }
                    else if ( $.isPlainObject( conf.data ) ) {
                        // As an object, the data given extends the default
                        $.extend( request, conf.data );
                    }


                    var obj = {};
                    obj = createSchema(obj);

                    //create json for form values
                    var jsonform= form2js('filterForm', '.', false);
                    request.operationType='search';
                    request.startIndex = request.start+1;
                    request.endIndex = request.start+ request.length;
                    request.filterObject = jsonform;
                    obj.payload  = request;

                    settings.jqXHR = sendAjax(conf.url, obj,function(res){
                        if(res.err){
                            processError(res.err);
                        }else if(res.payload && res.payload.result && res.payload.result.length > 0){
                            var json = res.payload.result[0];
                            if(json){
                                var dataSet = {};
                                dataSet.recordsTotal = json.totalRecords;
                                dataSet.recordsFiltered = json.totalRecords;
                                dataSet.data = json.records;

                                json = dataSet;
                                cacheLastJson = $.extend(true, {}, json);
                                if ( cacheLower != drawStart ) {
                                    json.data.splice( 0, drawStart-cacheLower );
                                }
                                json.data.splice( requestLength, json.data.length );
                                drawCallback( json );
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }
                else {
                    json = $.extend( true, {}, cacheLastJson );
                    json.draw = request.draw; // Update the echo for each response
                    json.data.splice( 0, requestStart-cacheLower );
                    json.data.splice( requestLength, json.data.length );

                    drawCallback(json);
                }
            }
        };

        // Register an API method that will empty the pipelined data, forcing an Ajax
        // fetch on the next draw (i.e. `table.clearPipeline().draw()`)
        $.fn.dataTable.Api.register( 'clearPipeline()', function () {
            return this.iterator( 'table', function ( settings ) {
                settings.clearCache = true;
            } );
        } );

        tabeleRef = $('#branches').DataTable({
            "processing": true,
            "serverSide": true,
            "bSort" : false,
            "bFilter" : false,
            "dom": 't<"paginationInfo"i><"lengthbox"l><"customPagination"p><"clear">',
            "aoColumns": [
                { "stitle": "ID","mData": "branchId" },
                { "stitle": "Branch Code","mData": "branchCode" },
                { "stitle": "Parent Code","mData": "parentCode" },
                { "stitle": "Date Created","mData": "dateCreated" },
                { "stitle": "Branch Limit","mData": "transLimit" },
                { "stitle": "Status","mData": "status" }
            ],
            "columnDefs": [
                {
                    "targets": 0,
                    "render": function ( data, type, full, meta ) {
                        return meta.row + meta.settings._iDisplayStart + 1;
                    }
                }
            ],
            "ajax": $.fn.dataTable.pipeline( {
                url: 'branchmanagement/action/getlistofnewbranches',
                method: 'POST',
                pages: 5 // number of pages to cache,

            } )
        });



        // custom toolbar
        $("div.toolbar").html('<div class="text-right"><img src="img/logo.png" alt="SmartAdmin" style="width: 111px; margin-top: 3px; margin-right: 10px;"></div>');
        /* END COLUMN FILTER */

    };
    var filterButtonClicked = false;
    $(document ).ready(function(e){
        $("#fromDate,#toDate").attr("autocomplete", "off");

        $.validator.addMethod("dateformat", function(value, element) {
            return this.optional( element ) || <%-regexes.DATE%>.test(value);
        }, 'date format should be dd-M-yyyy');
/*
                $("#filter").on('change keyup ', function() {
                    if(this.value )
                        $('#fromDate,#toDate').datepicker("setDate","") ;
                });

*/

        $("#filterForm").validate({
            errorClass : "error",
            rules : {

                'filter' :{
                    required:{
                        depends: function(element) {
                            return $("#fromDate,#toDate").val() == ''
                        }
                    }
                },
                'fromDate' :{
                    required: function () {
                        return $('#filter' ).val() == ""
                    }
                },
                'toDate' :{
                    required: function () {
                        return $('#filter' ).val() == ""
                    }
                }
            },
            messages : {
                'filter' : {
                    required :  'This field is required'
                },
                'fromDate' :{
                    required :  'This field is required'
                },
                'toDate' :{
                    required :  'This field is required'
                }
            }
        });

        // START AND FINISH DATE
     //$('#fromDate,#toDate' ).val(getTodayDate('dd-M-yy'));

        $('#fromDate').datepicker({
            dateFormat : 'dd-M-yy',
            changeYear: true,
            yearRange: "-100:+0",
            prevText : '<i class="fa fa-chevron-left"></i>',
            nextText : '<i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i>',
            onSelect : function(selectedDate) {
                $('#fromDate' ).parent().removeClass('state-error');
                $('#fromDate' ).parent().addClass('state-success');
                $('#fromDate' ).next().css('display','none');
                //$('#filter' ).val("");
                $('#endDate').datepicker('option', 'minDate', selectedDate);
            }
        });

        $('#toDate').datepicker({
            dateFormat : 'dd-M-yy',
            changeYear: true,
            yearRange: "-100:+0",
            prevText : '<i class="fa fa-chevron-left"></i>',
            nextText : '<i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i>',
            onSelect : function(selectedDate) {
                $('#toDate' ).parent().removeClass('state-error');
                $('#toDate' ).parent().addClass('state-success');
                $('#toDate' ).next().css('display','none');
                //$('#filter' ).val("");
                $('#fromDate').datepicker('option', 'maxDate', selectedDate);
            }
        });

    });
    function bindFormSubmit() {
        $("#filterForm .submit").click(function(event) {
            if($("#filterForm").valid()) {
                if (tabeleRef) {

                    filterButtonClicked = true;
                    tabeleRef.draw();

                }
                else
                    pagefunction();

                return false;
            }
        });
        $('button[type="submit"]').removeAttr('disabled');
        $('#btnExport').removeAttr('disabled');
        $("#btnExport").click(function(event) {
           if($("#filterForm").valid()){
                var filter = form2js( 'filterForm', '.', false );
                filter.operationType='export';
                var queryString = decodeURIComponent($.param(filter));
                var q = encryptAndEncodeString(queryString);
                var url = '/exportdatamanagement/exportlistofnewbranches?q=' + q;
                var win = window.open(url, '_blank');
                win.focus();
                return false;
          }
            event.preventDefault();
            return false;
        });
    }
    // load related plugins

    loadScript("js/plugin/datatables/jquery.dataTables.min.js", function(){
        loadScript("js/plugin/datatables/dataTables.colVis.min.js", function(){
            loadScript("js/plugin/datatables/dataTables.tableTools.min.js", function(){
                loadScript("js/plugin/datatables/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js", function(){
                    loadScript("js/plugin/datatable-responsive/datatables.responsive.min.js", bindFormSubmit)
                });
            });
        });
    });


</script>
```

As you can see, i'm using 2 buttons namely "Search" and "Export".

When clicking the "Search" button, the required data is successfully fetched from the db but when exporting it to excel, i'm making another call to the server to fetch the same data to be exported.

1. Can we export the data received from the first Ajax call so that we don't need to make a second Ajax call to the server for fetching the same data ?

Comment: The point of the pipeline example is to limit the amount of ajax calls.  For example, normally when using server side data, a ajax call goes out for every page click.  This example with cache the specified number of pages in a JS array to cut down on some of those calls.  What are you trying to achieve exactly?

Comment: @ Paul Zepernick, i have updated  the question. See it please.